# Matplotlib: Polar projection transData.transform gives wrong values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to insert a small icon at a particular point in a polar graph.

From what I understand, `fig.figimage(image, x, y)` receives `x,y` as display coordinates. I use `ax.transData.transform_point((theta, radius))`, but this doesn't work correctly.

My code is the following:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

t = arange(0, 2*pi, 0.01)
r = ones(t.size)

fig = gcf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(t, r)

x, y = ax.transData.transform((pi/4, 1.0))
img = imread('die.png')
fig.figimage(img, x, y)

show()
```

[Here's the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpcTH.png), whereas the lower left corner of the `img` should be touching the blue line at 45 degrees and radius 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to draw the figure first before the transform can give you the correct coordinates.

```
fig.canvas.draw()
x, y = ax.transData.transform((pi/4, 1.0))
```

This is because the axes position of the polar plot is only determined when the figure is actually drawn. Trying to transform something beforehands will lead to wrong coordinates.

In general I would recommend using an `AnnotationBbox` instead of a `figimage` in such case.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage, AnnotationBbox

t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
r = np.ones(t.size)

fig = plt.gcf()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')
ax.plot(t, r)

img = plt.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qe6z.png')

imagebox = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.2)
imagebox.image.axes = ax

ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, (np.pi/4, 1.0),
                    box_alignment=(0., 0),
                    xycoords='data', pad=0)

ax.add_artist(ab)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That worked! Can you explain or link me to the relevant documentation to understand why this fixes it? Also, I'm not sure how to mark your answer as the correct one. Maybe, similar to how I can't upvote, it's because my account is very recent.

Comment: Wow, what a great answer. Thank you very much!